# Prevent WooCommerce checkout if minimum quantity for a category is not reached unless another category is added

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart, checkout

I am doing a check in the cart to apply a rule that if a item from the  **chilled** category is added, a minimum of 3 chilled category items are required to check out. - This works.

However, if an item from the **bundles** category is also added, then the above chilled rule should not be enforced.

e.g. Minimum of 3 chilled category items required, unless a bundle item is in the cart, in which case, disregard the chilled rule.

I have the minimum 3 chilled rule working, but I can't get the code to exclude this rule if a item from the bundles category is detected?

Based on [Prevent WooCommerce checkout if minimum quantity for a specific category is not reached](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69790593/11987538) answer code, this is my attempt:

```php
function action_woocommerce_check_cart_items() {
    // Only run on the cart or checkout pages
    if ( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {     
        // Minimum
        $minimum = 3;
        
        // Category
        $category = 'chilled';
        $category2 = 'bundles';
        
        // Initialize
        $total = 0;
        
        // Loop through cart items        
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {        
            // Product id
            $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

            // Has certain category
            if ( has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {              
                // Add to total
                $total += $cart_item['quantity'];
            }elseif (has_term ($category2, 'product_cat', $product_id)) {
                break;
                
            }
        }
        
        // When total is greater than 0 but less than the minimum
        if ( $total > 0 && $total < $minimum ) {
            // Notice
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( '<strong>A minimum of %s products are required from the CHILLED category before checking out.</strong>', 'woocommerce' ), $minimum ), 'error' );
            
            // Optional: remove proceed to checkout button
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );
        }
    }
}   
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items' , 'action_woocommerce_check_cart_items', 10, 0 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

End the execution in the current loop will not suffice, you also need to add an extra rule to the if condition.

So you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_check_cart_items() {
    // Only run on the cart or checkout pages
    if ( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {     
        // Minimum
        $minimum = 3;
        
        // Category
        $category = 'chilled';
        $category_2 = 'bundles';
        
        // Initialize
        $total = 0;
        $flag = true;
        
        // Loop through cart items        
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {        
            // Product id
            $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

            // Has certain category
            if ( has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {              
                // Add to total
                $total += $cart_item['quantity'];
            // Has other category
            } elseif ( has_term( $category_2, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) { 
                // Break loop
                $flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        
        // When total is greater than 0 but less than the minimum & flag is still true
        if ( ( $total > 0 && $total < $minimum ) && $flag ) {
            // Notice
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( 'A minimum of %s products are required from the %s category before checking out.', 'woocommerce' ), $minimum, $category ), 'error' );
            
            // Optional: remove proceed to checkout button
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );
        }
    }
}   
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items' , 'action_woocommerce_check_cart_items', 10, 0 );
```